# Function to Conduct a Kruskal Wallis Tests for Multiple Comparison of Variables using R

Tags: r, statistics, difference, statistical-test, kruskal-wallis

**Issue:**

I have a dataset that doesn't meet the assumptions to conduct an ANOVA, so I need to conduct a non-parametric alternative such as the **Kruskal Wallis test**. Overall, I have seven parameters and I want to conduct multiple pairwise comparisons between them.

I have found a function to conduct this type of analysis but the overall output is definitely not correct.

Would anyone be able to lend a hand?

Many thanks if anyone can help.

**R Code:**

```
Outcomes <- c("Low.Freq", "High.Freq", "Peak.Freq", "Delta.Freq", "Delta.Time", "Peak.Time", 
              "Center.Freq", "Start.Freq", "End.Freq")

#Multiple Kruskall Wallis test the Raw Data for acoustic parameters
Multiple_Kruskal_Test<-sapply(Outcomes, function(my) {
                              f <- as.formula(paste(my, "~Species", sep=""))
                              summary(kruskal.test(f, data=New_Acoustic_Parameters))
                              })
```

**Incorrect Output:**

```
      Low.Freq    High.Freq   Peak.Freq   Delta.Freq  Delta.Time  Peak.Time   Center.Freq Start.Freq  End.Freq   
 [1,] "1"         "1"         "1"         "1"         "1"         "1"         "1"         "1"         "1"        
 [2,] "1"         "1"         "1"         "1"         "1"         "1"         "1"         "1"         "1"        
 [3,] "1"         "1"         "1"         "1"         "1"         "1"         "1"         "1"         "1"        
 [4,] "1"         "1"         "1"         "1"         "1"         "1"         "1"         "1"         "1"        
 [5,] "1"         "1"         "1"         "1"         "1"         "1"         "1"         "1"         "1"        
 [6,] "-none-"    "-none-"    "-none-"    "-none-"    "-none-"    "-none-"    "-none-"    "-none-"    "-none-"   
 [7,] "-none-"    "-none-"    "-none-"    "-none-"    "-none-"    "-none-"    "-none-"    "-none-"    "-none-"   
 [8,] "-none-"    "-none-"    "-none-"    "-none-"    "-none-"    "-none-"    "-none-"    "-none-"    "-none-"   
 [9,] "-none-"    "-none-"    "-none-"    "-none-"    "-none-"    "-none-"    "-none-"    "-none-"    "-none-"   
[10,] "-none-"    "-none-"    "-none-"    "-none-"    "-none-"    "-none-"    "-none-"    "-none-"    "-none-"   
[11,] "numeric"   "numeric"   "numeric"   "numeric"   "numeric"   "numeric"   "numeric"   "numeric"   "numeric"  
[12,] "numeric"   "numeric"   "numeric"   "numeric"   "numeric"   "numeric"   "numeric"   "numeric"   "numeric"  
[13,] "numeric"   "numeric"   "numeric"   "numeric"   "numeric"   "numeric"   "numeric"   "numeric"   "numeric"  
[14,] "character" "character" "character" "character" "character" "character" "character" "character" "character"
[15,] "character" "character" "character" "character" "character" "character" "character" "character" "character"
>
```

**Data**

```
   structure(list(ID = 1:150, Low.Freq = c(435L, 94103292L, 1L, 
2688L, 8471L, 28818L, 654755585L, 468628164L, 342491L, 2288474L, 
3915L, 411L, 267864894L, 3312618L, 5383L, 8989443L, 1894L, 534981L, 
9544861L, 3437614L, 475386L, 7550764L, 48744L, 2317845L, 5126197L, 
2445L, 8L, 557450L, 450259742L, 21006647L, 9L, 7234027L, 59L, 
9L, 605L, 9199L, 3022L, 30218156L, 46423L, 38L, 88L, 396396244L, 
28934316L, 7723L, 95688045L, 679354L, 716352L, 76289L, 332826763L, 
6L, 90975L, 83103577L, 9529L, 229093L, 42810L, 5L, 18175302L, 
1443751L, 5831L, 8303661L, 86L, 778L, 23947L, 8L, 9829740L, 2075838L, 
7434328L, 82174987L, 2L, 94037071L, 9638653L, 5L, 3L, 65972L, 
0L, 936779338L, 4885076L, 745L, 8L, 56456L, 125140L, 73043989L, 
516476L, 7L, 4440739L, 612L, 3966L, 8L, 9255L, 84127L, 96218L, 
5690L, 56L, 3561L, 78738L, 1803363L, 809369L, 7131L, 0L, 35502443L, 
88864L, 94L, 850L, 89628L, 261319L, 4848L, 97341913L, 75L, 82481L, 
806L, 14L, 7L, 88L, 912102577L, 48L, 169L, 6949L, 165L, 35969L, 
44L, 955L, 9L, 43090317L, 3L, 7905L, 596L, 7262304L, 4246710L, 
68L, 0L, 6859264L, 85725268L, 985L, 861158777L, 95L, 386L, 8773L, 
765L, 6798L, 18L, 9L, 32472L, 3L, 647698334L, 27918648L, 836L, 
188837805L, 968L, 88656L, 5823702L), High.Freq = c(6071L, 3210L, 
6L, 7306092L, 6919054L, 666399L, 78L, 523880161L, 4700783L, 4173830L, 
30L, 811L, 341014L, 780L, 44749L, 91L, 201620707L, 74L, 1L, 65422L, 
595L, 89093186L, 946520L, 6940919L, 655350L, 4L, 6L, 618L, 2006697L, 
889L, 1398L, 28769L, 90519642L, 984L, 0L, 296209525L, 487088392L, 
5L, 894L, 529L, 5L, 99106L, 2L, 926017L, 9078L, 1L, 21L, 88601017L, 
575770L, 48L, 8431L, 194L, 62324996L, 5L, 81L, 40634727L, 806901520L, 
6818173L, 3501L, 91780L, 36106039L, 5834347L, 58388837L, 34L, 
3280L, 6507606L, 19L, 402L, 584L, 76L, 4078684L, 199L, 6881L, 
92251L, 81715L, 40L, 327L, 57764L, 97668898L, 2676483L, 76L, 
4694L, 817120L, 51L, 116712L, 666L, 3L, 42841L, 9724L, 21L, 4L, 
359L, 2604L, 22L, 30490L, 5640L, 34L, 51923625L, 35544L, 59644L, 
306266049L, 27533545L, 61L, 2L, 5970L, 88728373L, 664355064L, 
30548207L, 254317L, 868L, 460L, 80L, 7003L, 86L, 916570L, 3124L, 
24L, 1217766L, 1L, 95912L, 59634328L, 0L, 761341L, 95L, 5L, 65269L, 
849L, 30408L, 99L, 9L, 78771L, 1288L, 70567L, 4L, 449L, 77L, 
90L, 4520867L, 7492578L, 825466852L, 349445L, 23L, 9094L, 20L, 
233144L, 21L, 82L, 216201L, 15988509L, 8594969L), Peak.Freq = c(87005561L, 
9102L, 994839015L, 42745869L, 32840L, 62737133L, 2722L, 24L, 
67404881L, 999242982L, 3048L, 85315406L, 703037627L, 331264L, 
8403609L, 3934064L, 50578953L, 370110665L, 3414L, 12657L, 40L, 
432L, 7707L, 214L, 68588962L, 69467L, 75L, 500297L, 704L, 1L, 
102659072L, 60896923L, 4481230L, 94124925L, 60164619L, 447L, 
580L, 8L, 172L, 9478521L, 20L, 53L, 3072127L, 2160L, 27301893L, 
8L, 4263L, 508L, 712409L, 50677L, 522433683L, 112844L, 193385L, 
458269L, 93578705L, 22093131L, 6L, 9L, 1690461L, 0L, 4L, 652847L, 
44767L, 21408L, 5384L, 304L, 721L, 651147L, 2426L, 586L, 498289375L, 
945L, 6L, 816L, 46207L, 39135L, 6621028L, 66905L, 26905085L, 
4098L, 0L, 14L, 88L, 530L, 97809006L, 90L, 6L, 260792844L, 9L, 
833205723L, 99467321L, 5L, 8455640L, 54090L, 2L, 309L, 299161148L, 
4952L, 454824L, 729805154L, 395358183L, 2643L, 314568967L, 80599L, 
34187604L, 304L, 86161503L, 8685L, 99892L, 13687L, 54L, 98470989L, 
7L, 55L, 879113565L, 106660L, 902524584L, 71116L, 43689323L, 
863L, 6930L, 5L, 965L, 70107282L, 29588L, 9L, 59L, 39159L, 64446665L, 
6034008L, 96L, 35850L, 670200431L, 17145L, 311804L, 31L, 7747522L, 
2270162L, 611L, 36121267L, 22900823L, 3L, 323L, 844738L, 956L, 
41433111L, 22694748L, 85899937L, 42L, 9497559L), Delta.Freq = c(5L, 
78L, 88553L, 794L, 5L, 3859122L, 782L, 36L, 8756801L, 243169338L, 
817789L, 8792384L, 7431L, 626921743L, 9206L, 95789L, 7916L, 8143453L, 
6L, 4L, 6363L, 181125L, 259618L, 6751L, 33L, 37960L, 0L, 2L, 
599582228L, 565585L, 19L, 48L, 269450424L, 70676581L, 7830566L, 
4L, 86484313L, 21L, 90899794L, 2L, 72356L, 574280L, 869544L, 
73418L, 6468164L, 2259L, 5938505L, 31329L, 1249L, 354L, 8817L, 
3L, 2568L, 82809L, 29836269L, 5230L, 37L, 33752014L, 79307L, 
1736L, 8522076L, 40L, 2289135L, 862L, 801448L, 8026L, 5L, 15L, 
4393771L, 405914L, 71098L, 950288L, 8319L, 1396973L, 832L, 70L, 
1746L, 61907L, 8709547L, 300750537L, 45862L, 91417085L, 79892L, 
47765L, 5477L, 18L, 4186L, 2860L, 754038591L, 375L, 53809223L, 
72L, 136L, 509L, 232325L, 13128104L, 1692L, 8581L, 23L, 7L, 5L, 
1269784L, 55451L, 614683290L, 645L, 1L, 16L, 93L, 19250054L, 
2695713L, 78271L, 7L, 6L, 691373L, 0L, 278L, 42857L, 8L, 94900646L, 
27796603L, 72716820L, 12816272L, 7738L, 596087L, 64091692L, 2261964L, 
371L, 978998L, 127180699L, 94L, 60969L, 23L, 66L, 13L, 26408810L, 
4L, 65L, 8687L, 72140L, 566656L, 263437292L, 9088L, 46496188L, 
215843L, 510L, 51989L, 16736709L, 147L, 8823L, 82L), Delta.Time = c(1361082L, 
7926L, 499L, 5004L, 3494530L, 213L, 64551179L, 70L, 797L, 5L, 
72588L, 86976L, 5163L, 635080L, 3L, 91L, 919806257L, 81443L, 
3135427L, 4410972L, 5810L, 8L, 46603718L, 422L, 1083626L, 48L, 
15699890L, 7L, 90167635L, 446459879L, 2332071L, 761660L, 49218442L, 
381L, 46L, 493197L, 46L, 798597155L, 45342274L, 6265842L, 6L, 
3445819L, 351L, 1761227L, 214L, 959L, 908996387L, 6L, 3855L, 
9096604L, 152664L, 7970052L, 32366926L, 31L, 5201618L, 114L, 
7806411L, 70L, 239L, 5065L, 2L, 1L, 14472831L, 122042249L, 8L, 
495604L, 29L, 8965478L, 2875L, 959L, 39L, 9L, 690L, 933626665L, 
85294L, 580093L, 95934L, 982058L, 65244056L, 137508L, 29L, 7621L, 
7527L, 72L, 2L, 315L, 6L, 2413L, 8625150L, 51298109L, 851L, 890460L, 
160736L, 6L, 850842734L, 2L, 7L, 76969113L, 190536L, 7855L, 3L, 
946706344L, 789239369L, 93L, 802838635L, 291929L, 55L, 52L, 6L, 
93601L, 5L, 179260L, 44006L, 220573L, 42152733L, 7L, 534618382L, 
3L, 768153L, 206921L, 59L, 324331L, 52641160L, 74563L, 24L, 4L, 
24L, 1046L, 862L, 71454L, 98894864L, 27686265L, 72584615L, 3L, 
106L, 2L, 67439L, 6408L, 2160359L, 862L, 998L, 453L, 26179L, 
5857483L, 7796517L, 659L, 261L, 0L, 25779L, 688592899L), Peak.Time = c(1465265L, 
452894L, 545076172L, 8226275L, 5040875L, 700530L, 1L, 3639L, 
20141L, 71712131L, 686L, 923L, 770569738L, 69961L, 737458636L, 
122403L, 199502046L, 6108L, 907L, 108078263L, 7817L, 4L, 6L, 
69L, 721L, 786353L, 87486L, 1563L, 876L, 47599535L, 79295722L, 
53L, 7378L, 591L, 6607935L, 954L, 6295L, 75514344L, 5742050L, 
25647276L, 449L, 328566184L, 4L, 2L, 2703L, 21367543L, 63429043L, 
708L, 782L, 909820L, 478L, 50L, 922L, 579882L, 7850L, 534L, 2157492L, 
96L, 6L, 716L, 5L, 653290336L, 447854237L, 2L, 31972263L, 645L, 
7L, 609909L, 4054695L, 455631L, 4919894L, 9L, 72713L, 9997L, 
84090765L, 89742L, 5L, 5028L, 4126L, 23091L, 81L, 239635020L, 
3576L, 898597785L, 6822L, 3798L, 201999L, 19624L, 20432923L, 
18944093L, 930720236L, 1492302L, 300122L, 143633L, 5152743L, 
417344L, 813L, 55792L, 78L, 14203776L, 853437L, 964147297L, 895424L, 
57L, 361L, 68512L, 5L, 9395L, 53562L, 83436598L, 6372L, 33387L, 
51L, 71L, 2340L, 246145L, 58519L, 15442937L, 362336019L, 213917L, 
5874213L, 4550L, 644668065L, 3712371L, 5928L, 8833L, 7L, 2186023L, 
61627221L, 37297L, 716427989L, 21387L, 26639L, 13428L, 66290997L, 
6657L, 16L, 52256745L, 1179L, 578L, 4602L, 7L, 5L, 23530306L, 
545453L, 6930L, 9120798L, 415L, 229600784L, 8862829L), Center.Freq = c(61907L, 
8709547L, 300750537L, 45862L, 91417085L, 79892L, 47765L, 5477L, 
18L, 4186L, 2860L, 754038591L, 375L, 53809223L, 72L, 136L, 4700783L, 
4173830L, 30L, 811L, 341014L, 780L, 44749L, 91L, 201620707L, 
74L, 1L, 65422L, 595L, 89093186L, 946520L, 6940919L, 48744L, 
2317845L, 5126197L, 2445L, 8L, 557450L, 450259742L, 21006647L, 
9L, 7234027L, 59L, 9L, 651547554L, 45554L, 38493L, 91055218L, 
38L, 1116474L, 2295482L, 3001L, 9L, 3270L, 141L, 53644L, 667983L, 
565598L, 84L, 971L, 555498297L, 60431L, 6597L, 856943893L, 607815536L, 
4406L, 79L, 4885076L, 745L, 8L, 56456L, 125140L, 73043989L, 516476L, 
7L, 4440739L, 754038591L, 375L, 53809223L, 72L, 136L, 509L, 232325L, 
13128104L, 1692L, 8581L, 23L, 5874213L, 4550L, 644668065L, 3712371L, 
5928L, 8833L, 7L, 2186023L, 61627221L, 37297L, 716427989L, 21387L, 
26639L, 13428L, 66290997L, 7747522L, 2270162L, 611L, 36121267L, 
7492578L, 825466852L, 349445L, 23L, 9094L, 20L, 233144L, 21L, 
82L, 7738L, 596087L, 64091692L, 2261964L, 371L, 978998L, 127180699L, 
94L, 60969L, 23L, 66L, 35969L, 44L, 955L, 9L, 43090317L, 3L, 
7905L, 596L, 7262304L, 4246710L, 68L, 0L, 6859264L, 85725268L, 
985L, 861158777L, 95L, 386L, 8773L, 602L, 2740L, 8065L, 61370968L, 
429953765L), Start.Freq = c(426355L, 22073538L, 680374L, 41771L, 
54L, 6762844L, 599171L, 108L, 257451851L, 438814L, 343045L, 4702L, 
967787L, 1937L, 18L, 89301735L, 366L, 90L, 954L, 7337732L, 70891703L, 
4139L, 10397931L, 940000382L, 7L, 38376L, 878528819L, 6287L, 
738366L, 31L, 47L, 5L, 6L, 77848L, 2366508L, 45L, 3665842L, 7252260L, 
6L, 61L, 3247L, 448348L, 1L, 705132L, 144L, 7423637L, 2L, 497L, 
844927639L, 78978L, 914L, 131L, 7089563L, 927L, 9595581L, 2774463L, 
1651L, 73509280L, 7L, 35L, 18L, 96L, 1L, 92545512L, 27354947L, 
7556L, 65019L, 7480L, 71835L, 8249L, 64792L, 71537L, 349389666L, 
280244484L, 82L, 6L, 40L, 353872L, 0L, 103L, 1255L, 4752L, 29L, 
76L, 81185L, 14L, 9L, 470775630L, 818361265L, 57947209L, 44L, 
24L, 41295L, 4L, 261449L, 9931404L, 773556640L, 930717L, 65007421L, 
341175L, 287376310L, 104L, 17L, 45616L, 48L, 0L, 34436L, 413591913L, 
799218L, 81L, 139678L, 87142L, 314040L, 1L, 486L, 30120565L, 
95L, 421252320L, 586616452L, 45L, 2L, 1470L, 391034L, 59182022L, 
75L, 267101L, 267L, 2L, 183169L, 814298L, 2L, 68720184L, 8256L, 
3L, 26054L, 391397L, 5724L, 61464405L, 40455L, 8066605L, 1L, 
474008L, 9577335L, 1L, 443959L, 2454751L, 2250L, 30385546L, 22091L, 
7973L), End.Freq = c(71000996L, 11613579L, 71377155L, 1942738L, 
8760748L, 79L, 455L, 374L, 8L, 5L, 2266932L, 597833L, 155488L, 
3020L, 4L, 554L, 4L, 16472L, 1945649L, 668181101L, 649780L, 22394365L, 
93060602L, 172146L, 20472L, 23558847L, 190513L, 22759044L, 44L, 
78450L, 205621181L, 218L, 69916344L, 23884L, 66L, 312148L, 7710564L, 
4L, 422L, 744572L, 651547554L, 45554L, 38493L, 91055218L, 38L, 
1116474L, 2295482L, 3001L, 9L, 3270L, 141L, 55595L, 38451L, 8660867L, 
14L, 96L, 345L, 6L, 44L, 8235824L, 910517L, 1424326L, 87102566L, 
53644L, 667983L, 565598L, 84L, 971L, 555498297L, 60431L, 6597L, 
856943893L, 607815536L, 4406L, 79L, 7L, 28978746L, 7537295L, 
6L, 633L, 345860066L, 802L, 1035131L, 602L, 2740L, 8065L, 61370968L, 
429953765L, 981507L, 8105L, 343787257L, 44782L, 64184L, 12981359L, 
123367978L, 818775L, 123745614L, 25345654L, 3L, 800889L, 3087787L, 
2L, 143387L, 552269L, 285146L, 86L, 95L, 95207L, 88122L, 999L, 
7L, 206341870L, 11725048L, 7398L, 9686L, 2913230L, 771L, 56634L, 
267L, 87834983L, 1910L, 79718L, 172348L, 5042905L, 47066L, 88747L, 
9668242L, 8175066L, 51L, 4578L, 359354L, 942L, 2244547L, 4799667L, 
44L, 245003L, 31132L, 25L, 58351180L, 1L, 24331L, 74483974L, 
46771553L, 46750L, 6L, 3L, 14L, 31554881L, 1L, 13L), Species = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Country = c("Holland", "Holland", "Holland", 
"Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", 
"Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", 
"Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", 
"Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "France", "France", "France", 
"France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
"France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
"France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "Holland", 
"Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", 
"Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", 
"Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", 
"Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "France", 
"France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
"France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
"France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
"France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
"France", "France", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", 
"Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", 
"Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", 
"Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", 
"France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
"France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
"France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "Holland", 
"Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-150L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the `summary`, we may use `tidy`

```
library(purrr)
Outcomes <- setdiff(Outcomes, "Center.Freq") # Centre.Freq column not present
map_dfr(setNames(Outcomes, Outcomes), function(my) {
                     f <- as.formula(paste(my, "~Species", sep=""))
                     broom::tidy(kruskal.test(f, data=New_Acoustic_Parameters))
                              }, .id = "Outcomes")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 × 5
  Outcomes   statistic p.value parameter method                      
  <chr>          <dbl>   <dbl>     <int> <chr>                       
1 Low.Freq       2.03    0.362         2 Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test
2 High.Freq      0.252   0.881         2 Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test
3 Peak.Freq      3.53    0.171         2 Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test
4 Delta.Freq     1.66    0.436         2 Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test
5 Delta.Time     1.35    0.509         2 Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test
6 Peak.Time      2.41    0.299         2 Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test
7 Start.Freq     4.35    0.114         2 Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test
8 End.Freq       2.19    0.334         2 Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test
```

Comment: Hello, Akrun. I hope you are well! I attached another data frame with the variable Center.Freq. I've been playing around with the code to incorporate this variable into the Kruskal Wallis test and I keep on getting error messages saying that the y value is missing. Would you be able to provide any clarity with this? Many thanks if you can help.

Comment: @AliceHobbs in your data, I find `Centre_Freq` instead of `Center.Freq` which is showed in `Outcomes`.  If I change the name, it is working fine for me

Comment: Yes, I realised that was a typo. The Center.Freq is not shown in the output table. Why is Center.Freq in the Outcomes object. If you can explain, this will be fantastic, please. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @AliceHobbs In the `Outcomes` object you have `Centre.Freq` which I guess you created manually where as the `colnames(New_Acoustic_Parameters)` shows `Centre_Freq`.  Probably you have typed it incorrectly?

Comment: Yes! I have corrected the colnames(New_Acoustic_Parameter) typo. The column in the dummy data is now labelled Center.Freq. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: What I mean is why "Center.Freq" written in this code? Outcomes <- setdiff(Outcomes, "Center.Freq"). Was it because of Center.Freq was missing in my dummy dataset or is this how you calculate the differences between pairs of parameters. Sorry for sounding like a novice

Comment: @AliceHobbs that was because in the earlier data, `Center.Freq` was not present.  You can ignore that line `Outcomes <- setdiff(Outcomes, "Center.Freq")` i.e. use only from `map_dfr(...`

Comment: I get it! Thank you and thank you again, it worked really well.